OPEN_APP_FEATURE is not working from google assistant just opened the app without featureParams and received ACTION_MAIN instead ACTION_VIEW
I'm developing a app to open specific feature through Google assistant. Everything is working as expected through App Actions Test tool. it opened the app and move to specific feature in the app. I received Intent.ACTION_VIEW and featureParams. But when I run through Google Assistant through voice command or text it just opens the app with Intent.ACTION_MAIN and no feature params.
Steps I followed.

Login same account in android devices
Login same account in android studio
Login same account in Google Play console
Upload build in internal testing google play console.

Here is my shortcuts


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <capability android:name="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
        <intent
            android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
            android:targetClass="ae.gov.adnoc.ui.onboarding.splash.view.SplashActivity"
            android:targetPackage="ae.gov.adnoc">
            <parameter
                android:name="feature"
                android:key="featureParam" />
        </intent>
    </capability>
    <!-- Short and long labels must be @string resource. -->
    <shortcut
        android:shortcutId="shop"
        android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/clickCollect"
        android:enabled="false">
        <capability-binding android:key="actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE">
            <parameter-binding
                android:key="feature"
                android:value="@array/clickCollect_synonyms" />
        </capability-binding>
    </shortcut>
</shortcuts>



Here is my manifiest


  <activity
            android:name=".ui.onboarding.splash.view.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">
                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="adnocdist.page.link" />
                <data android:host="links.adnocmob.adnocdistribution.ae" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="adnocdist" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true"
                tools:targetApi="m">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <!-- Required reference to App Actions shortcuts.xml file. -->
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.shortcuts"
                android:resource="@xml/shortcuts" />
        </activity>



Activity where I'm handling the intents
private fun Intent.handleIntent() {
    when (action) {
        // When the BII is matched, Intent.Action_VIEW will be used
        Intent.ACTION_VIEW -> handleIntent(extras)
        // Otherwise start the app as you would normally do.
        else -> {}
    }
}

/**
 * Use extras provided by the intent to handle the different BIIs
 */
private fun handleIntent(data: Bundle?) {
    val feature = data?.getString("featureParam")
    feature?.let {
        when (it){
            BiiIntents.featureClickCollect -> Toast.makeText(
                    this@SplashActivity,
                    "Navigate to mainactivity and trigger cc flow",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            BiiIntents.featureEv -> {
                Toast.makeText(
                        this@SplashActivity,
                        "Navigate to mainactivity and trigger ev flow",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
}

